# Can I use Django to make non-web python apps as a data scientist?

Tags: python, django, data-science

I'm a data scientist, and I make apps using python. Where I make a lot of connections with databases, build and deploy my code on the cloud and I use models training and visualization.
My question is:
Is Django useful for making non-web apps?
if not are they any other frameworks? (similar to spring-boot for java)
Best regards

Comment: You might want to look at [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) to evaluate if it suits your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Django is a web framework which comes with many preinstalled apps. This will make your application bulkier than it is required.

For your usecase, you need not to use any frameworks. Just code it in python and you can use the available library to perform db operations.

If you are deploying your app on the cloud, and want expose some endpoints to trigger any of your internal functions, go with `Flask` framework. It is a light weight micro web framework

Comment: You don't have to use any of the "preinstalled apps", so "makes it bulkier than it is required" is just FUD.

Comment: @AKX Yeah right. In this context why do someone has to install a battery included monolithic framework and go through removing whatever isn't required with breaking (may be) stuffs. Django isn't recommended for small use cases because of the same ideology right? and obviously the django way

Comment: Who says what Django is or isn't recommended for? For instance, Django has a very capable ORM and a world-class database migration system that could be useful for OP, even if all they do is "API views" (or they could surface REST APIs for their ORM models automatically with DRF).

Comment: When not to use django search will give the answer (Those answers are from developers like you and i). I'm not denying the facts of what django could do. But just because, it is capable to do, you need to use it. I'm not buying it.

Answer (score 0):

I would contrast the first answer and say absolutely you can use Django with no intentions of building a front end.  The ORM is so powerful and easy to use along with the out-of-the-box signaling system among many other features.  In my opinion a little extra "bulk" is worth the tools you have at your disposal with it.  And of course you always have the option to add the front end later if you like.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, Now I'm confusing a litlle bit.

Comment: @Jordan Hyatt, How ORM and signaling is going to help here ? I dont think you could use ORM without creating a model (correct me if i'm wrong). Labidi's ask is for non-web apps. Django is literally a web framework. I dont see any need for using django here. All the task could be done with standalone python, for time taking task use Pika. just few lines of code in flask for trigger endpoint. work is done

Comment: @LiquidDeath an ORM is a programmatic way of interacting with a relational database using the native language of your application.  It inherently has nothing to do with "web" although it is obviously useful in supporting web apps (which is why Django developed their own).  ORM's are extremely powerful and for me personally I prefer Django's ORM to others such as SQLAlchemy.  Therefore, I find Django to be useful even for projects that don't have a web front end.  In the end there is no "right" answer here.  It will ultimately come down to your particular requirements and preferences.

Comment: Right. But in here to use django's ORM, you need to have your models set up right ? for a  data scientist, who doesn't want a webapp, doing all the model setup and going through django's way is not required. All you need is just python, pika, and whatever light framework to expose an api

Comment: This is true if your data source and refresh/retrain is straight forward and simple.  I have a project that pulls from multiple data sources and files.   It uses Django's scripting system to continually pull new data from all the sources.  It uses the signaling system to refresh attributes on related models and to refresh engineered features.  It uses the ORM to filter out data that should be left out of training data.  Sure all of this could be done with vanilla python, pandas etc.  But for me building out the models and using these tools made it a lot easier, automated and scaleable.

Comment: I've also figured out a nifty way of using the ORM to store trained ML models right in the database, as well as related attributes of that trained model (parameters, performance metrics etc.) so that I can re-train and make predictions seamlessly using the ORM rather than having to manually pickle it, store it as a flat file and recall it.